How to make a recommended book clickable to trigger new recommendations in Streamlit?
I have a book recommendation system built with Streamlit and machine learning. When a user clicks on one of the 24 initial books displayed, the app shows a larger image of the book and recommends 6 similar books. However, when a user clicks on one of the recommended books, it don't a larger image of the book and also without recommending new books. I want to make the recommended books also trigger new recommendations when clicked, just like the initial 24 books.
import pickle
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import random
from st_clickable_images import clickable_images

# Load data
items_matrix = pickle.load(open("model/book_matrix.pkl", "rb"))
books_dict = pickle.load(open("model/book_dict.pkl", "rb"))
final_rating = pickle.load(open("model/books.pkl", "rb"))

# Function to recommend similar books
def recommend(book_name):
    top_10_similar_items = list(
        items_matrix.loc[book_name].sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[:10].index
    )
    return top_10_similar_items

# Create a DataFrame for the books
books_df = pd.DataFrame(books_dict)

# Filter books with valid images
books_with_images = books_df[
    books_df["image_url"].notnull() & books_df["image_url"].ne("")
]

# Function to display recommendations
def display_recommendations(book):
    recommendations = recommend(book)
    # Exclude the selected book from recommendations
    recommendations = [rec for rec in recommendations if rec != book]
    random_recommendations = random.sample(recommendations, 6)
    return random_recommendations

# Pagination
def paginate(items, page_number, items_per_page=24):
    start_index = (page_number - 1) * items_per_page
    end_index = min(start_index + items_per_page, len(items))
    return items[start_index:end_index]

# Streamlit interface
st.header("Book Recommender System Using Machine Learning")

unique_books = sorted(set(books_with_images["title"].values))
unique_authors = sorted(set(books_with_images["author"].values))

# Search bar
search_query = st.text_input("Search for a book or author")

# Search criteria by title or author
search_criteria = st.radio("Search by", ("Title", "Author"))

# Display the number of available books
st.write(f"Total number of books: {len(unique_books)}")

# Pagination
page_number = st.sidebar.number_input(
    "Page", value=1, min_value=1, max_value=(len(unique_books) - 1) // 24 + 1
)

# Filter books based on search
if search_query:
    if search_criteria == "Title":
        unique_books = [
            book for book in unique_books if search_query.lower() in book.lower()
        ]
    elif search_criteria == "Author":
        unique_books = [
            book
            for book in unique_books
            if search_query.lower()
            in books_with_images.loc[books_with_images["title"] == book, "author"]
            .iloc[0]
            .lower()
        ]

# Select books for the current page
selected_books = paginate(unique_books, page_number)

# Create a list of image URLs and titles for the selected books
image_urls = [
    final_rating.loc[final_rating["title"] == book, "image_url"].iloc[0]
    for book in selected_books
]
titles = selected_books

# Use st_clickable_images to make the images clickable with titles
clicked = clickable_images(
    image_urls,
    titles=titles,
    div_style={"display": "flex", "justify-content": "center", "flex-wrap": "wrap"},
    img_style={"margin": "5px", "height": "200px", "width": "20%"},
)

# If an image is clicked, display the image in large with its title, then the recommendations below
if clicked > -1:
    # Use a container to center the image with custom CSS
    with st.container():
        # Add CSS style to center the image and caption
        st.markdown(
            """
            <style>
            .centered-content {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
            }
            </style>
            """,
            unsafe_allow_html=True,
        )

        # Apply the centered style to the image and caption
        st.markdown(
            """
            <div class="centered-content">
                <img src="{0}" width="250">
                <div><b>{1}</b></div>
            </div>
            """.format(
                image_urls[clicked], titles[clicked]
            ),
            unsafe_allow_html=True,
        )
    st.write("\n")
    # Display a title before the recommendations
    st.markdown(
        """
            <style>
            .centered-subheader {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 20px 0;  # Add space above and below the title
            }
            </style>
            <h2 class="centered-subheader">You might like</h2>
            """,
        unsafe_allow_html=True,
    )
    st.write("\n")
    rec_books = display_recommendations(titles[clicked])
    rec_image_urls = [
        final_rating.loc[final_rating["title"] == book, "image_url"].iloc[0]
        for book in rec_books
    ]
    rec_titles = rec_books
    # Use st_clickable_images to make the images clickable with titles
    rec_clicked = clickable_images(
        rec_image_urls,
        titles=rec_titles,
        div_style={"display": "flex", "justify-content": "center", "flex-wrap": "wrap"},
        img_style={"margin": "5px", "height": "200px", "width": "25%"},
    )
    # If a recommended image is clicked, display the image in large with its title
    if rec_clicked > -1:
        st.image(
            rec_image_urls[rec_clicked], use_column_width=False, width=300
        )  # Adjust the width of the image
        st.write(rec_titles[rec_clicked])

# Pagination management
if len(unique_books) > 24:
    st.sidebar.write("Page", page_number, "of", (len(unique_books) - 1) // 24 + 1)

I tried to modify the function that show recommandation to include the recommendation function for the recommended books as well, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I expected that when a recommended book is clicked, it would show a larger image of the book and recommend new books, just like the initial 24 books. I've also tried to make some loops and others. I need you help
